# Maximise a parametrised $\sin^2$ function

Tags: probability, trigonometry, optimization, convex-optimization, quantum-mechanics

How to find the optimal value of $k$ that maximises $\sin^{2}((2k + 1)\theta)$ assuming $ \theta \in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ and $k$ is a natural number.

As per my understanding the value of $k$ must initially decrease till $\theta$ reaches $\frac{\pi}{8}$ then it will start to increase and will go to infinity for $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$

Any suggestions how to show it mathematically and get an equation that gives back $k$?

Comment: For any fixed $\theta$ we will get some value of $k$. Now the objective is to observe the changes in the value of $k$ as $\theta$ varies by plotting $\theta$ on $x-axis$ and $k$ on $y-axis$

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Here $k$ is a natural number. Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the post to make it clear.